# how to optimize query with contains clause

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, contains

When I use `contains()` function on title field with a parameter with length 1  (for example  ..... `where contains(title , '%x%')  > 0` ) 
my query response time slows down.
As I know it's because of the length of the parameter (i.e `length ('x') = 1` )

Is there any solution to optimize such query?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but is there a possibility that the columns that have a smaller length than your search length are skipped?

Comment: thank you, but I don't think so! its impossible for my title field its length is greater than 2 always.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using CONTAINS just to check whether title contains the letter x? That is a very inefficient way. Use this instead:

```
... where title like '%x%'
```

"like" simply returns yes or no, it doesn't calculate a score like contains does. And by not wrapping "title" within a function, the Oracle optimizer is free to use an index on "title" if you defined one. (If you didn't you may consider adding one.)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, but I should score similarity rate and using CONTAINS is inevitable. In addition it's notable that my field is now indexed with a certain type of indices(domain index)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the length of the search string.
A search for `%xxxxxxxxxxx%` will take a similar time.

The problem is in the **leading %** which disables the *index range scan*. To match `%x%` **the whole index must be scaned.**

You should try to limit the search for only  `x%`, i.e. without the leading `%` which is in general impossible as you get only subset of the results.

In some cases it is possible and I'll illustrate it on a simple example.

Suppose you are searching a prefix of a table and the table can by both unqualified and qualified.

You must search for `%x%` to get a match on  both of the strings:

```
XTABLE   
OWNER.XTABLE2
```

What you can do is define the dot as a [`whitespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cdatadic.htm#CCREF0218)
which will split the owner form the table name and index three tokes:

```
XTABLE   
OWNER
XTABLE2
```

That will enable to search for `x%` only ending with index range scan with better performance.

Comment: I've just tested it now that search with '%x%' takes 52 seconds, but search with '%xx%' only takes less than a second! what is its reason really?!

Comment: You'll have to provide your index definition and some information about your data to be able to help. But probably the best way to analyze is to run both queries with the 10046 trace and see the diference....